# Can there be a numerical system in which logarithms can be expressed in terms of exponentials in closed form?

Tags: real-analysis, number-fields, nonstandard-analysis

The invention of complex numbers allowed to express trigonometric functions through hyperbolic ones in closed form.

Is there possible an extension of real/complex numbers in which logarithms and inverse trigonometric functions can be expressed in terms of exponentials/trigonometric functions and vice versa in closed form?

P.S. I have asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769459/can-there-be-a-numerical-system-in-which-logarithms-can-be-expressed-in-terms-of?noredirect=1#comment3611127_1769459) but is seems people there just do not understand the question.

What I am talking about is something like this:
$$\frac1\pi\ln \left(\frac{w-\frac{z}{\pi }}{w-1+\frac{z}{\pi }}\right)=\frac1z\cos (2wz)$$

or this:

$$\ln(\sin(w + z)) = 1/z \cos(2 w z)$$

Where $w$ is some element of the extended field, not a complex number. Is this possible?

Comment: Anything is possible: take the set of solutions $z,w$ to your equation, as a Riemann surface inside $\mathbb{C}^2$. Then on that set, $w$ is a function satisfying your equation, by definition. The field of meromorphic functions of the $z$ variable pulls back, from projection $(z,w) \mapsto z$ to live inside the meromorphic functions on that Riemann surface. Not a satisfying or explicit solution, more like a solution by definition.

Comment: @Ben McKay what you are saying is interesting. Will this extension satisfy the usual notions of a "numerical " field? Is it possible to somehow derive other algebraic properties of such extension?

Comment: I don't know. What is a numerical field? It won't be a number field, or an algebraic extension field.

Comment: @Ben McKay fine, I would not expect it to be an algebraic extension. By "numerical field" I understood a field that would have the majority of properties of real/complex numbers (that is commutativity and associativity of multiplication etc). At least what allows to call say, hyperreal numbers still "numbers".

Comment: It is a field: commutative, associative, distributive, and every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: "people there just do not understand the question". Well, I don't mind confessing my thickness, but I don't understand the question either. I don't know what a "numerical field" is, and I don't know how you're going to extend the exponential/logarithm to that set. Except tautological answers like BenMcKay's, I just don't know what new "numbers" you'd expect. Just because you state "I wish I knew some system in which such and such formula is true" does not mean you ask a well-formed question and that everybody is supposed to understand its meaning.

Comment: I think the question is whether the log function can be expressed using a finite number of compositions of arithmetic operations and the exponential function, starting with a finite number of constants ($w$ in Anixx's notation). The answer is "obviously" no but I think it is not trivial to prove it.

Comment: Related subsequent question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297454/is-there-any-precedent-in-mathematics-where-closed-form-relations-between-trigon

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested at a related site, the natural log can be expressed via the shadow of a hyperfinite partial sum of the harmonic series.

Comment: What you are referring to? What site?..

Comment: I meant at this site at a different question.

Comment: Oh I see. But this is still not closed form, is it?