# Has there been proposed an extension of real numbers that connects logarithms and exponents in closed form?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, number-fields

Complex numbers do connect trigonometric functions with hyperbolic functions and exponents in closed form. Has anybody ever proposed an algebraic system that would connect in a similar way trigonometric functions and inverse trigonometric functions (logarithms)?

I am asking this because taking roots for instance can be expressed through exponentiation while logarithms are standing quite apart. If logarithms can be expressed via exponentiation, then all elementary functions can be expressed via addition, multiplication and power.

Comment: Does $\lim_{a\to 0} \frac{x^a-1}{a} = \log(x)$ count?

Comment: @Suvrit interesting hit, actually! I think it does not count per se, but can be a potential basis for contruction of a numerical system (for instance, adding such $\epsilon$ that $\frac{x^\epsilon-1}{\epsilon}=\log x)$.

Comment: Maybe it would help to try and state more precisely what "connect" should mean?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge By "connect" I meant "express in closed form".

Comment: @Anixx : Let's assume we want your equation to work nicely under substitutions. Then:

$\frac{(x^2)^\epsilon - 1}{\epsilon} = \log x^2$

Then $\frac{x^{2 \epsilon} - 1}{\epsilon} = 2 \log x$

Using the equation, we can rewrite this:

$(\log x)(\epsilon \log x + 2) = 2 \log x$

And finally:

$\epsilon (\log x)^2 = 0$

So assuming some nice idea of substitution, you get something that shouldn't work. You have to use some idea of "round to a real number" for this to work.

Comment: Essentially, this is the idea behind one form of nonstandard analysis - you can introduce infinitesimals, as long as you also introduce some idea of "round to a real number".

Comment: @user44191 my question is whether something that connects exponents with logarithms in closed form has been already proposed by somebody. Not necessarily based on the user Survit's relation.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/237919/can-there-be-a-numerical-system-in-which-logarithms-can-be-expressed-in-terms-of (if you agree, please upvote this comment so that it appears "above the fold")